# Back to previous view and scrollbar - best practices SPA

Tags: angular, navigation, frontend, soa

I'm currently implementing simple frontend application in Angular and I wonder what are best practices for following scenario.

I have two views: one of them is page with table of products (about 100), user is able to click on the product item and navigate to the second view, which is product details view. The product details view in some circumstances should go back to view with table and scroll down to element which I clicked.

The question is: what is best place to store information about expected scroll position?

Comment: try this, https://medium.com/lacolaco-blog/introduce-router-scroller-in-angular-v6-1-ef34278461e9

Answer (score 0):

My guess is I would store that kind of information

- in a `Service` but the data will not persist if the client refresh the entire page.
- or in `localStorage` to keep the data if the client quit the app and come back later.